# Class Design - The responsibilities for the classes

Tags: oop, design-patterns, class-design, fmod

Say, I have 2 classes which are Audio and AudioManager. My question is, should these functions

```
void Play();
void Resume();
void Pause();
void Stop();
void Load();
```

be within Audio class or AudioManager?

Well, what I did is put them all into AudioManager class, but I'm not so sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about them as if they were real word concepts. In fact they are. If you insert your CD to a CD Player will you tap the CD or the Player? Of course the Player. The functions you listed belong to the player.

I think that the name `AudioManager` does not describe its task. In general the use of the name `Manager` is discouraged since it is a broad concept. In your case `Player` would be better.

Audio in your case is just a data structure and should not have those functions.

*Just a remark: most of the functions in your post are straightforward but `Load` is somehow confusing. Does It load a track or it loads the CD into the player or?*

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I thought! (except for the example, I think I will use your way whenever I encounter similar problems). Well, as for Load(), it loads a "Track" to the "CD"

Comment: and thanks for the audio manager to player suggestion. Will change it.